# Prevent user from submiting multiples times a form

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, controls

I know some other subjects are related to that one, but I have a specification I didn't find anywhere else.

On my website, people can, after filling a small form (name/firstname/email), get a chance to win an entry ticket for an event. What I'd like to do, is to prevent them playing multiple times for the same event. Why ? Because some of them are playing more than once with just changing the email.

So what I thought was using a javascript cookie so I can check if the user has already submitted a form. But the thing is that we have a lot of event, and they need to be able to play all of them. So if I store something in a cookie, they will only be able to play once, am I correct ?

Thanks,

Comment: Give each event a unique ID and concatenate the played IDs together in the cookie with, for example, a pipe symbol |. Then you'll be able to check which have been played and which haven't. Note that users can just disable or delete cookies to bypass this, though.

Comment: Try getting some more user specific info from the user. Maybe ask for user real adress, or first 3 numbers of the their social security number, or .... If 2 users have exactly the same data is disqualified. If a user wins, but his data is not validated when he comes for the price, is disqualified.

Comment: @Graham That would make sense. And yes I'm aware about that it can be easily bypassed, but I'm thinking most of the users won't find that. But then again maybe I'm wrong, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @user510990 Most users probably wouldn't figure that out. If you *really* want to prevent repeat usage you could try something like tracking IP & user-agent combinations but that's a bit excessive for this case...!

Comment: @Graham eheh yes it would be excessive! I'll go and try to setup your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No you are not correct..
You can set your code to check if a cookie exists and then if it exists you can just dont give any chance of wining the entry ticket.

Beside you can use multibale cookies for each game or just use a read command to cookie and then you can create a new cookie with information with last cookie and add to the current cookie the information about the currrent game.

I hope I made sense...